# How can I use Node.js native import/export in version 9

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I want to use Node native support for import/export with NPM packages. To start I'm running cuccumberjs version 3.1.0. However when I run this command:

```
/usr/local/bin/node --experimental-modules ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js
```

I get an error:

```
(node:42011) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
/full/path/to/test/directory/features/support/getWindowLocation.js:2
import {runJsInBrowser} from "./runJsInBrowser.mjs";
^^^^^^
```

All my automation test run fine until I try to convert one of my scripts to a ES module and import it. Here is an snippet from the file:

`runJsInBrowsers.mjs`

```
export default async function runJsInBrowser(
    browserDriver,
    windowFunc,
    waitForReturn = true,
    timeOut = 10000
) {
    ...
};
```

--

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "tests",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Test for testing.",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "dependencies": {
        "chromedriver": "^2.0",
        "cucumber": "^3.1",
        "selenium-webdriver": "^3.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    }
}
```